# Google Mobile Services (GMS): NullPointerPointerException from calling String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)'

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-services, android-6.0-marshmallow

I received this stack trace from Firebase Crash Reporting:

`Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
bsz.d (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:6098)
bta.run (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:1028)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)`

The crash occurred on a device running API 23.

Unlike some other stack traces this one doesn't mention which Activity the crash occurred in.

The stack trace indicates the error is connected to Google Play Services. In my app I use Google Play Services version 9.4.0.

Here are the GMS and Firebase libraries that I use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
```

I haven't been able to find a similar problem to this. But `DynamiteModules` does seem to be connected to Firebase.

Does anyone know what could be causing this crash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be useful to post the full stack traceback. Or is that short list all there was in the report?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The stack trace that I posted in the question was the complete stack trace that was reported in the crash log.

Comment: Shoot, that's not a lot to go on. I'd go find the source code for DynamiteModulesC and look at line 6098. The key question is what string is it trying to downcase that's null in this report? Could it be a string you passed in to an API call, perhaps one that came out of another API call?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have access to the DynamiteModulesC source code. Maybe it could be a String that I passed in to an API call somewhere in my code like you said. Cheers.

Comment: i have the same crash report using Firebase 9.2.1, 16 errors, 6 users, and exactly same type of device in all instances, LGE Nexus 5x, API 23

Comment: I have the same crash too, it happens on rooted phones.

Comment: I have the same crash too more than once. Also with the same LGE Nexus 5x. Always with Operator: T-Mobile.

Comment: Same here LGE Nexus 5x